# Login with fr3d ldapbundle & fos userbundle, user found but on DB insert username is null

Tags: symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle, sonata-user-bundle, fr3dldapbundle

(updated at the end)

I am having trouble registering any user from a specific LDAP as even after finding the user from LDAP, when it tries to register, the username is null, so it triggers a violation constraint and rollsback.
Am using Sonata User Bundle, FR3D LDAP Bundle and FOS User Bundle.

dev.log

```
[2018-01-30 16:06:09] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.username AS username_1, t0.username_canonical AS username_canonical_2, t0.email AS email_3, t0.email_canonical AS email_canonical_4, t0.enabled AS enabled_5, t0.salt AS salt_6, t0.password AS password_7, t0.last_login AS last_login_8, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token_9, t0.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at_10, t0.roles AS roles_11, t0.created_at AS created_at_12, t0.updated_at AS updated_at_13, t0.date_of_birth AS date_of_birth_14, t0.firstname AS firstname_15, t0.lastname AS lastname_16, t0.website AS website_17, t0.biography AS biography_18, t0.gender AS gender_19, t0.locale AS locale_20, t0.timezone AS timezone_21, t0.phone AS phone_22, t0.facebook_uid AS facebook_uid_23, t0.facebook_name AS facebook_name_24, t0.facebook_data AS facebook_data_25, t0.twitter_uid AS twitter_uid_26, t0.twitter_name AS twitter_name_27, t0.twitter_data AS twitter_data_28, t0.gplus_uid AS gplus_uid_29, t0.gplus_name AS gplus_name_30, t0.gplus_data AS gplus_data_31, t0.token AS token_32, t0.two_step_code AS two_step_code_33, t0.ab_number AS ab_number_34, t0.title AS title_35, t0.hire_date AS hire_date_36, t0.employment_status AS employment_status_37, t0.departure_date AS departure_date_38, t0.departure_reason AS departure_reason_39, t0.local_balance AS local_balance_40, t0.sick_balance AS sick_balance_41, t0.frozen_local_balance AS frozen_local_balance_42, t0.carry_forward_local_balance AS carry_forward_local_balance_43, t0.frozen_carry_forward_local_balance AS frozen_carry_forward_local_balance_44, t0.is_no_probation_leaves AS is_no_probation_leaves_45, t0.dn AS dn_46, t0.created_by AS created_by_47, t0.updated_by AS updated_by_48, t0.id AS id_49, t0.job_title_id AS job_title_id_50, t0.department_id AS department_id_51, t0.project_id AS project_id_52, t0.business_unit_id AS business_unit_id_53 FROM fos_user_user t0 WHERE t0.username_canonical = ? LIMIT 1 ["gpotest"] []
[2018-01-30 16:06:09] ldap_driver.DEBUG: ldap_search(dc=example,dc=mu, (&(&(ObjectClass=person))(sAMAccountName=gpotest)), [array]) {"action":"ldap_search","base_dn":"dc=example,dc=mu","filter":"(&(&(ObjectClass=person))(sAMAccountName=gpotest))","attributes":[]} []
[2018-01-30 16:06:09] security.INFO: User gpotest found on LDAP {"action":"loadUserByUsername","username":"gpotest","result":"found"} []
[2018-01-30 16:06:09] ldap_driver.DEBUG: ldap_bind(CN=gpotest,OU=Test,DC=example,DC=mu, ****) {"action":"ldap_bind","bind_rdn":"CN=gpotest,OU=Test,DC=example,DC=mu"} []
[2018-01-30 16:06:09] security.INFO: User has been authenticated successfully. {"username":null} []
[2018-01-30 16:06:09] doctrine.DEBUG: "START TRANSACTION" [] []
[2018-01-30 16:06:09] doctrine.DEBUG: INSERT INTO fos_user_user (username, username_canonical, email, email_canonical, enabled, salt, password, last_login, confirmation_token, password_requested_at, roles, created_at, updated_at, date_of_birth, firstname, lastname, website, biography, gender, locale, timezone, phone, facebook_uid, facebook_name, facebook_data, twitter_uid, twitter_name, twitter_data, gplus_uid, gplus_name, gplus_data, token, two_step_code, ab_number, title, hire_date, employment_status, departure_date, departure_reason, local_balance, sick_balance, frozen_local_balance, carry_forward_local_balance, frozen_carry_forward_local_balance, is_no_probation_leaves, dn, created_by, updated_by, job_title_id, department_id, project_id, business_unit_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) {"1":null,"2":null,"3":null,"4":null,"5":true,"6":null,"7":"","8":"2018-01-30 16:06:09","9":null,"10":null,"11":["ROLE_EMPLOYEE"],"12":"2018-01-30 16:06:09","13":"2018-01-30 16:06:09","14":null,"15":null,"16":null,"17":null,"18":null,"19":"u","20":null,"21":null,"22":null,"23":null,"24":null,"25":null,"26":null,"27":null,"28":null,"29":null,"30":null,"31":null,"32":null,"33":null,"34":null,"35":null,"36":null,"37":null,"38":null,"39":null,"40":0,"41":0,"42":0,"43":0,"44":0,"45":false,"46":"CN=gpotest,OU=Test,DC=example,DC=mu","47":null,"48":null,"49":null,"50":null,"51":null,"52":null} []
[2018-01-30 16:06:09] doctrine.DEBUG: "ROLLBACK" [] []
[2018-01-30 16:06:09] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\NotNullConstraintViolationException: "An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO fos_user_user (username, username_canonical, email, email_canonical, enabled, salt, password, last_login, confirmation_token, password_requested_at, roles, created_at, updated_at, date_of_birth, firstname, lastname, website, biography, gender, locale, timezone, phone, facebook_uid, facebook_name, facebook_data, twitter_uid, twitter_name, twitter_data, gplus_uid, gplus_name, gplus_data, token, two_step_code, ab_number, title, hire_date, employment_status, departure_date, departure_reason, local_balance, sick_balance, frozen_local_balance, carry_forward_local_balance, frozen_carry_forward_local_balance, is_no_probation_leaves, dn, created_by, updated_by, job_title_id, department_id, project_id, business_unit_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null, null, 1, null, "", "2018-01-30 16:06:09", null, null, "a:1:{i:0;s:13:\"ROLE_EMPLOYEE\";}", "2018-01-30 16:06:09", "2018-01-30 16:06:09", null, null, null, null, null, "u", null, null, null, null, null, "null", null, null, "null", null, null, "null", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "CN=gpotest,OU=Test,DC=example,DC=mu", null, null, null, null, null, null]:  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'username' cannot be null" at E:\wamp64\www\acshrm\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 118 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\NotNullConstraintViolationException(code: 0): An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO fos_user_user (username, username_canonical, email, email_canonical, enabled, salt, password, last_login, confirmation_token, password_requested_at, roles, created_at, updated_at, date_of_birth, firstname, lastname, website, biography, gender, locale, timezone, phone, facebook_uid, facebook_name, facebook_data, twitter_uid, twitter_name, twitter_data, gplus_uid, gplus_name, gplus_data, token, two_step_code, ab_number, title, hire_date, employment_status, departure_date, departure_reason, local_balance, sick_balance, frozen_local_balance, carry_forward_local_balance, frozen_carry_forward_local_balance, is_no_probation_leaves, dn, created_by, updated_by, job_title_id, department_id, project_id, business_unit_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null, null, 1, null, \"\", \"2018-01-30 16:06:09\", null, null, \"a:1:{i:0;s:13:\\\"ROLE_EMPLOYEE\\\";}\", \"2018-01-30 16:06:09\", \"2018-01-30 16:06:09\", null, null, null, null, null, \"u\", null, null, null, null, null, \"null\", null, null, \"null\", null, null, \"null\", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \"CN=gpotest,OU=Test,DC=example,DC=mu\", null, null, null, null, null, null]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'username' cannot be null at E:\\wamp64\\www\\acshrm\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\lib\\Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\AbstractMySQLDriver.php:118, Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'username' cannot be null at E:\\wamp64\\www\\acshrm\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\lib\\Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOStatement.php:107, PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'username' cannot be null at E:\\wamp64\\www\\acshrm\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\lib\\Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOStatement.php:105)"} []
```

As you can see it says user found with the right username:

User gpotest found on LDAP {"action":"loadUserByUsername",**"username":"gpotest"**,"result":"found"}

But then after binding:

security.INFO: User has been authenticated successfully. {**"username":null**}

However, by using the commented out Online LDAP server config in config.yml below, I was able to connect and authenticated successfully:

```
[2018-01-24 23:46:03] ldap_driver.DEBUG: ldap_bind(uid=gauss,dc=example,dc=com, ****) {"action":"ldap_bind","bind_rdn":"uid=gauss,dc=example,dc=com"} []
[2018-01-24 23:46:03] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.name AS name_1, t0.roles AS roles_2, t0.id AS id_3 FROM fos_user_group t0 INNER JOIN fos_user_user_group ON t0.id = fos_user_user_group.group_id WHERE fos_user_user_group.user_id = ? [188] []
[2018-01-24 23:46:03] security.INFO: User has been authenticated successfully. {"username":"gauss"} []
[2018-01-24 23:46:03] doctrine.DEBUG: "START TRANSACTION" [] []
[2018-01-24 23:46:03] doctrine.DEBUG: UPDATE fos_user_user SET last_login = ?, updated_at = ? WHERE id = ? ["2018-01-24 23:46:03","2018-01-24 23:46:03",188] []
[2018-01-24 23:46:03] doctrine.DEBUG: "COMMIT" [] []
[2018-01-24 23:46:03] security.DEBUG: Stored the security token in the session. {"key":"_security_user"} []
```

Here are my relevant file contents:

composer.json

```
"fr3d/ldap-bundle": "^3.0",
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^2.0",
"sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.23",
"sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.1",
"sonata-project/user-bundle": "^4.0",
"symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
```

config.yml

```
fr3d_ldap:
    # driver:
        # host: ldap.forumsys.com
    # user:
        # baseDn: 'dc=example,dc=com'
        # attributes:
            # - { ldap_attr: uid,  user_method: setUsername }
            # - { ldap_attr: mail,  user_method: setEmail }
            # - { ldap_attr: cn,  user_method: setFirstname }
            # - { ldap_attr: sn,  user_method: setLastname }
        # filter: (&(ObjectClass=person))

    driver:
        host: example.mu
        accountFilterFormat: (&('sAMAccountName'=%s))
        username: gpotest
        password: apassword
        bindRequiresDn: false
    user:      
        baseDn: 'dc=example,dc=mu'
        attributes:
            - { ldap_attr: sAMAccountName,  user_method: setUsername }
            - { ldap_attr: mail,  user_method: setEmail }
            # - { ldap_attr: cn,  user_method: setFirstname }
            - { ldap_attr: sn,  user_method: setLastname }
        filter: (&(ObjectClass=person))
        usernameAttribute: 'sAMAccountName'

# Sonata User Bundle
sonata_user:
    security_acl: false
    manager_type: orm # can be orm or mongodb
    class:
        user: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
        group: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
    admin:                  # Admin Classes
        user:
            class:          LeavesOvertimeBundle\Admin\UserAdmin
            controller:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD
            translation:    SonataUserBundle

fos_user:
    db_driver:      orm # can be orm or odm
    firewall_name:  main
    user_class:     Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User #Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser

    group:
        group_class:   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group #Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseGroup
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager

    service:
        user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager

    from_email:
        address:        '%from_email%'
        sender_name:    AS
```

security.yml

```
security:
    erase_credentials: false
    # Sonata User Bundle
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
#    acl:
#        connection: default

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER:
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN
        ROLE_EMPLOYEE:
            - ROLE_USER
        SONATA:
            - ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_PAGE_EDIT  # if you are using acl then this line must be commented

    access_decision_manager:
        strategy: unanimous

    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [fos_userbundle, fr3d_ldapbundle]
        fr3d_ldapbundle:
            id: fr3d_ldap.security.user.provider
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        # Disabling the security for the web debug toolbar, the profiler and Assetic.
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        # -> custom firewall for the admin area of the URL
        admin:
            switch_user:        true
            pattern:            /admin(.*)
            fr3d_ldap:          ~
            context:            user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle # - looking back at this code, this was probably an issue, but I remember trying combination of every provider I have above. In my final solution this must be removed so that it takes the chain provider
                login_path:     /admin/login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /admin/login_check
                failure_path:   null
                default_target_path: /admin/dashboard
                always_use_default_target_path: true
            logout:
                path:           /admin/logout
                target:         /admin/login
            anonymous:          true

        main:
            switch_user:        true
            fr3d_ldap:          ~
            pattern:             .*
            context:             user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /login_check
                failure_path:   null
            logout:             true
            anonymous:          true
```

User class: (I have removed the irrelevent fields)

```
namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity;

use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;
use FR3D\LdapBundle\Model\LdapUserInterface;

class User extends BaseUser implements LdapUserInterface
{

    /**
     * @var int $id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @var string|null
     */
    protected $dn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if (empty($this->roles)) {
            $this->roles[] = 'ROLE_EMPLOYEE';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $dn
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setDn($dn) {
        $this->dn = $dn;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getDn() {
        return $this->dn;
    }
```

Extended classes above basically lead to FOSUserBundle's user class for username property
https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/blob/4.x/src/Entity/BaseUser.php
https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/blob/4.x/src/Model/User.php
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php

Overridden user.orm.xml: (I have removed the irrelevent fields)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                  http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <entity name="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User" table="fos_user_user" repository-class="MyBundle\Repository\UserRepository">

        <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
            <generator strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>
        <field name="dn" column="dn" type="string" length="255" nullable="true" />

    </entity>

</doctrine-mapping>
```

Parent definition:
https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/blob/4.x/src/Resources/config/doctrine/BaseUser.orm.xml

**Update 1**: Still couldn't make it work so we tried to put 'mail' in place of samaccountname and, I don't know why if I was in the middle of debugging that affected my token, but it worked. Email was working as a username. Logged out and tried it with another one and it worked.  Strangely after me trying to add a parameter to be saved, mail as username stopped working. This time when I made another person test, his email didn't work but his samaccountname (the thing I was trying to make work all this time) worked... At this point I have no idea what the hell is going on anymore.

**Update 2**
Here is the log using mail instead of sAMAccountName for setUsername method (after that it inserts in DB correctly). Another weird thing is givenName attr that contains firstName doesn't return anything, but using a AD explorer from MS, I can see that it has the firstName.:

```
[2018-02-05 11:42:51] ldap_driver.DEBUG: ldap_search(dc=example,dc=mu, (&(sAMAccountName=leaves)), [array]) {"action":"ldap_search","base_dn":"dc=example,dc=mu","filter":"(&(sAMAccountName=leaves))","attributes":[]} []
[2018-02-05 11:42:51] security.INFO: User leaves found on LDAP {"action":"loadUserByUsername","username":"leaves","result":"found"} []
[2018-02-05 11:42:51] ldap_driver.DEBUG: ldap_bind(CN=Leaves_Test HRM,OU=06 IT,DC=example,DC=mu, ****) {"action":"ldap_bind","bind_rdn":"CN=Leaves_Test HRM,OU=06 IT,DC=example,DC=mu"} []
[2018-02-05 11:42:51] security.INFO: User has been authenticated successfully. {"username":"Leaves_Test.HRM@email.com"} []
```

And config.yml:

```
driver:
    host: example.mu
#        accountDomainName: example
    accountDomainNameShort: example
#        accountFilterFormat: (&('sAMAccountName'=%s))
    username: leaves
    password: P@55w0rd
user:      
    baseDn: '%base_dn%'
    attributes:
        - { ldap_attr: mail,  user_method: setUsername }
        - { ldap_attr: mail,  user_method: setEmail }
        - { ldap_attr: cn,  user_method: setFirstname }
        - { ldap_attr: sn,  user_method: setLastname }
#        filter: (&(ObjectClass=person))
    usernameAttribute: 'sAMAccountName'
```

All in all, I get the feeling that at the moment of retrieving information, I am only able to pull mail, cn, sn attributes. Also, see at the first line of the log at the end of the line, there is attributes":[]. Is it normal to be empty?

Comment: Most seems ok, except for the User class. Why in the user class do you have `use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;` instead of `use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;`? Also there is no ORM annotations like in my article. In particular you are missing `protected $id;` - that would be very important! Not sure if you need `__toString()` or not.

Comment: I have Sonata User bundle because it is an adaptation of FOS user to be used in Sonata Admin's environment. The orm definitions are in the xml file and $id is present in my file, I just removed anything not related to LDAP to keep the post short.

Comment: You still getting the  Integrity Constraint error null on username in the log? Maybe you can show updated log with specific error?

Comment: @AlvinBunk See update 2

Comment: Hi there Rishi. Everything looks good in your logs. In my logs I get this: `security.INFO: User has been authenticated successfully. {"username":"abunk"} []`. Then after that comes some doctrine.DEBUG statements to update the fos_user table. This means the user is authenticated! Congratulations! You should only need to make minor modifications from here based on what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was I was only getting like email, sn, cn information after binding with MS Active Directory, not even samaccountname was stored in my User object.

**The solution is to use the bundle's custom hydrator:**

https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/cookbook/custom_hydrator.md.
Through this you will be able to get access to every attributes in the LDAP record you searched for.
If you follow the documentation it is all you need to fix the said issue.

However, in my version I import existing users via a CSV importer that includes their Usernames from LDAP but I cannot generate their DN string automatically, thus cannot login with only their Usernames, as their DN string contains specific "OU" information.

I solved this issue by loading the user from LDAP on every login to get up-to-date information like DN string and others that change frequently. I then either update an existing user or create a new one depending on repository search result, which also allows imported users to login and no duplicate entries of users. Thanks to ejkun for the elegant solution: https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle/issues/53#issuecomment-330905167. There's also a bonus on how to detect disabled accounts in AD.

**Here is my version of UserHydrator:**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use FR3D\LdapBundle\Hydrator\HydratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User;

class UserHydrator implements HydratorInterface
{
    protected $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * Populate a user with the data retrieved from LDAP.
     *
     * @param array $ldapEntry LDAP result information as a multi-dimensional array.
     *              see {@link http://www.php.net/function.ldap-get-entries} for array format examples.
     *
     * @return UserInterface
     */
    public function hydrate(array $ldapEntry)
    {
        if (!$ldapEntry) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!array_key_exists('samaccountname', $ldapEntry)) {
            return null;
        }

        $username = $ldapEntry['samaccountname'][0];
        $userFromDB = $this->entityManager->getRepository('ApplicationSonataUserBundle:User')->findOneBy(['username' => $username]);
        if ($userFromDB == null) {
            $user = new User();
            $user->setPassword('');
        }
        else {
            $user = $userFromDB;
        }

        // These are basically if statements without else in a short form, but do not call set methods with null
        array_key_exists('mail', $ldapEntry) ? $user->setEmail($ldapEntry['mail'][0]) : null;
        array_key_exists('givenname', $ldapEntry) ? $user->setFirstName($ldapEntry['givenname'][0]) : null;
        array_key_exists('sn', $ldapEntry) ? $user->setLastName($ldapEntry['sn'][0]) : null;
        array_key_exists('distinguishedname', $ldapEntry) ? $user->setDn($ldapEntry['distinguishedname'][0]) : null;
        /**
         * 512 = Enabled
         * 514 = Disabled
         * 66048 = Enabled, password never expires
         * 66050 = Disabled, password never expires
         */
        $user->setEnabled(array_key_exists('useraccountcontrol', $ldapEntry) ?
            $ldapEntry['useraccountcontrol'][0] == 512 || 66048 ? true : false : true);
        $user->setUsername($username);

        return $user;
    }
}
```

**Security.yml, reverse the chain provider order:**

```
providers:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [fr3d_ldapbundle, fos_userbundle]
    fr3d_ldapbundle:
        id: fr3d_ldap.security.user.provider
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username
```